# c++ operator<< overloading

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, operator-overloading

I am a beginner in C++ and I have the following problem.
When I run the following code in VS2013, I get an error.

```
class Y{
public:
    Y(int un_x, int un_y) 
    : x_(un_x), y_(un_y) {}

    int x() const {
        return x_;
    }
    int y() const {
        return y_;
    }
private:
    int x_;
    int y_;
};
class X{
    private:
       Y coord;
    public:
    // some code ...

        Y position() const {
           return coord;
        }

       void display(ostream& output) const {
            output << "The object is in position " << position();
       }
};




ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Y x){
     output<< "(" << x.x() << ", " << x.y() << ")" << endl;
     return output;
}
```

If I create an object some_object of class X and try to do:

```
cout << some_object ;
```

I get the followng error:

```
 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Y' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: You can't run that code because there's no actual code to run (like a main function). If you mean what you talked about below the code, there's no overload for outputting an `X`.

Comment: The code linked above by MooingDuck compiles and runs correctly under VS2013. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also, what does `X` have to do with this question?

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, `Y` has `Y::display` which is the problem.

Comment: If this is the *exact* code you're trying to compile the order of declaration is important. The operator << used in `X::display()` which pushes `position()` to the output stream has no definition of a compatible operator (yet). Move the operator as you have it *after* the `class Y` declaration, but *before* the `class X` declaration. Alternatively, just *declare* the `X::display()` method and implement it *after* the operator. either way, that operator has to be known (or at least declared) to the translate unit before `display()` can utilize it.

Comment: @WohzCraig, yes it's true, that's what Nik Bougalis already said, I tried it and it's working. thank you.

Comment: OP, please check the bottom of your question, you say you pass a class `X` but your error talks about a `Y` so you are either not showing us all of your significant code or you have a typo which will invalidate my answer

Comment: I think my question is clear, in main, I am creating an instance o class X and try to display its position which is an instance of another class (Y), using operator overloading, sorry if you didn't understand the question. My code is very long and I didn't want to include details in order to not confuse anyone.

Comment: I do understand it but your statments are contradictory as you'll see in the comments to my answer.  The error you show is inconsistent with the line you pasted in.  `cout << some_object;` wouldn't complain about lack an operator for `Y` it could complain about an operator for `X` which you haven't provided.

Comment: `cout << some_object ;` when `some_object` is a `X` will not produce an error that says `right-hand operand of type 'const Y'`.  The error message doesn't match the fact that you claim that `some_object` is an `X`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the `<<` operator defined *after* you try to use it – that is after the `display()` function? If so, you're going to need to either move it so that it is defined before use or, at the very least, declare it (that is, provide a prototype for it):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, Y x);
```

As a sidenote, you should pass the `Y` instance by constant reference instead of by value:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Y const& x);
```

Comment: Well, that will teach me to assume that X was irrelevent: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e58bfe2f577ee43 :(

Comment: +1 I really need to start reading answers before posting such long winded comments =P Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only overloaded the `operator <<` for class `Y`, you didn't overload it for class `X`. So it can't find one.  That aside you should probably pass `Y` into the operator by constant reference.

This is based upon your statement that you tried `cout << some_object` where `some_object` was an `X`.  If you tried `some_object.display()` you might yet run into the problem described by another user.

If that was a typo, then the answer moves instead to Nik's post, though I would again emphasize you should pass by reference or constant reference

Comment: I'm not downvoting you since the question lacks detail, but presumably, since he's overloaded `operator<<` for `Y`, the OP is passing an instance of `Y` and not `X` to `operator<<`.

Comment: @Praetorian but he didn't read the question and the statement right before it which yielded the error.

Comment: Oops, evidently I didn't read the question completely either. Apologies for the earlier comment. But given the error message, it *does* look like he's passing in an instance of `Y`.

Comment: The error message clarifies that he's _definitely_ passing a `Y`, not an `X`, despite what he claims.  Nevertheless, the question contradicts itself, so I'm removing the downvote.

Comment: :-) I did double take on that myself as I started to write what Nik wrote and then stopped.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks. and as stated if user corrects his question i'll remove post, and will redirect to Nik for his bigger problem :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks appreciated.  OP still doesn't seem to understand his contradiction

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because u have not declared ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Y x) as a friend function of Y.
try with making this function as friend function of Y as X dont have access two your declared function

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Y x);

Comment: Why would he need to do this? He only uses the public functions. You are incorrect.

Comment: u need this because operator<< for Y is not available to X.
and with a friend function he can achieve what he wanted.

Comment: Except that you don't.  It isn't defined as a class member it is available for anyone, it's defined as a free function. And as such he only makes use of public class methods.

Comment: The only reason I'm not downvoting you is that it you have only 1 rep and this question and your answer will likely be deleted... Just look at the other person who said the same thing who is also wrong.

Comment: will u please let me know why it is giving error ??

Comment: Why what is giving an error? Read Nik's answer or my own. In either case, your answer is wrong.